# Making a Objective-C Wrapper for a C++ Library

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, xcode, stl

I am trying to make a wrapper in Objective-C so I don't have to write c++ outside the library classes.

The Library main file is  `LLAHProcessor.h .cpp`

My Wrapper is `LLAHProcessorWrapper.h .mm`

It compiles fine, but when I add `LLAHProcessorWrapper` to other class, (Lets say an UIView) as a member variable I get hundreds of errors, like:

```
#include <map> : Map no such a file or directory
```

and in every c++ class/struct:

```
Expected specifier-qualifier list before ClassName
```

Is like compiler is not recognizing c++ code.

I wonder what am I missing here.
Does it has to be something with the fact I added this to Xcode Target Properties: ?

```
Other Link Flags : -lstdc++ -lz
```

Or maybe I need to add new flags here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's critical that `LLAHProcessorWrapper.h` contains no C++ code whatsoever. `LLAHProcessor.h` should be imported in your `.mm`. file, not in the `.h` file. Did you do that?

Comment: You also have .m files in the project?

Comment: @Chris I have lots of .m files. This is quite a big program.

Comment: @Ole, Ok, I understand what you mean to say, but if I do that how I am supposed to have member variables? Should I just add them outside the methods implementation inside the LLAHProcessorWrapper.mm file?

Comment: Use `void *` pointers for instance variables. See PeyloW's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `.m` files are compiled as C instead of C++.  Thus when the compiler comes across any C++ even in a header file while compiling a `.m` file, it will barf.

No doubt you have to put some C++ in your header file because your Objective C object wraps a C++ object, but there are ways around this.  One way would be to use a pointer to the C++ object and make use of the handy preprocessor define `__cplusplus` which is defined for C++ (and Objective-C++) but not for C (or Objective-C) e.g.

```
// LLAHProcessorWrapper.h

#if defined __cplusplus
class MyCPPClass;    // forward class declaration
#else
typedef struct MyCPPClass MyCPPClass;   // forward struct declaration
#endif

@interface MyOCClass : NSObject
{
@private
    MyCPPClass* cppObject;
} 

// methods and properties

@end
```

Since you never dereference the members of the cppObject outside of the `.mm` file it doesn't matter that you never provide a full definition for the struct.

You would `new` and `delete` the pointer in `-init` and `-dealloc` respectively.  You would include the full C++ class declaration in `LLAHProcessorWrapper.mm`.

Comment: Incase this is of use to anyone: I got caught out by still having `#include "MyCPPClass.h"` in the `LLAHProcessorWrapper.h`. It should be in the `LLAHProcessorWrapper.mm` instead.

Comment: I guess we can now use class extentions as well ? perhaps a better approach ?

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to create a `.mm` as you have done, and the compiler should take care of everything.

The caveat being that it is not safe to have anything C++ related in the `.h` files, since they can/will be imported by other Objective-C only files, and then everything breaks down. The main problem here is that you can not define C++ types directly as instance variables for your Objective-C wrapper class, unless every single `.m` file is renamed as a Objective-C++ `.mm` file.

The solution is to define the instance variables as `void*` in the header file, and access them with type casting from the implementation file. Easiest solution for this would be to access the instance variable using a private property that to the typecast for you.

Example code assuming `Foo` is a C++ class defined in `Foo.h`:

```
// FooWrapper.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FooWrapper : NSObject {
@private
  void* foo;
}
// Actual wrapper API for Foo…
@end


// FooWrapper.mm
#import "FooWrapper.h"
#include <map>
#include "Foo.h"

@interface FooWrapper ()
@property(nonatomic, assign) Foo* foo;
@end

@implementation FooWrapper
-(Foo*)foo {
  return (Foo*)foo;
}
-(void)setFoo:(Foo*)aFoo {
  foo = (void*)aFoo;
}
// Implementation of actual API for Foo…
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In any header (`.h`) file in which you want to refer to `LLAHProcessorWrapper`, use forward class definitions instead of imports, like so:

```
@class LLAHProcessorWrapper;
@interface SomeView : UIView {
  LLAHProcessorWrapper *wrapper;
}
```

and make sure that the corresponding implementation file has `#include LLAHProcessorWrapper.h` or `#import LLAHProcessorWrapper.h`.

Any implementation file in which you `#include` or `#import` your header must have `.mm` as its suffix if `LLAHProcessorWrapper.h` or *anything else in the entire include tree* has any C++ syntax at all. In this way, having one `.mm` file has a tendency to mean that huge portions of a codebase must have their files renamed to `.mm`.