# XCode - #include <map> in ml.hpp : No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, compilation, objective-c++

I'm trying to compile a C++ code (OpenCV) and I'm going to the end. I just have a few "No such file or directory" compile error into XCode 4 on those lines :

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

What may I include to make it find the "files" ?

I don't see.

**I use another project based on OpenCV with Objective-C inside for example that pass the compile process with success**, files are the same, and I checked all the Build settings lines one after the other, and it's all the same, except the search pathes that are updated to go to my own project folders. Folder architecture is the same...

**I've read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204239/making-a-objective-c-wrapper-for-a-c-library)** but it doesn't seems to be the solution as I should not have to add code anywhere of change files, since I don't use any of the code and the example project works fine like this. I've just included  into one of my .m files, exactly like the example project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've just included into one of my .m
>   files, exactly like the example
>   project.

If you want to use C++ classes, you must use Objective-C++. Your source files (not your header files, mind - the source files that #include them) must have a .mm extension.

Comment: what if I include the .hpp file in objective-c .h file?