# OpenCV && S2i Harpia on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, opencv, compilation

I created a new question because I've substantially the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781302/opencv-on-ubuntu-11-10), but I tried to compile a C example (not C++) automatically generated with S2i Harpia, using this command:

```
gcc test.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o test
```

Compilation fails because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574015/xcode-include-map-in-ml-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory), so compilation completes successfully if I rename the source file with ".mm" extension.
However, I installed everythin from scratch (I'm starting a new project) and it doesn't work from the beginning; instead I would want to work with the usual ".c" files.

The code I'm writing is in C -- not Objective-C and not C++ -- how can I tell the compiler to use the "old" OpenCV C interface?

EDIT: no problems with newest Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command, it worked for me:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` opencv.c -o open_cv `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Harpia, and to compile the source code auto generated. I had the same problem. I succeed replacing `gcc` by `g++`:

```
g++ pkg-config --cflags opencv test.c -o test pkg-config --libs opencv
```

What I understand from this example is that `gcc` is only for `C` code, as `g++` is for `C++` code.

Comment: Alessandro asked for a way to tell the compiler to use a different interface for parsing C. Since you are suggesting to use a different compiler, your answer doesn't fit the question.

Comment: Last line seems wrong to me too: **gcc is not only for C and g++ not only for C++**. Edit would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the libraries at the end of the row.

```
gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o test `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

It took me three days of installing and reinstalling opencv and dependancies until I found out the problem is with gcc. Somehow the order of which you write stuff in the command args is important now.

EDIT: The problem is not with the old interface or not. The compiler just doesn't link properly.