# error raises when i placed the compile source code as "According to file Type"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am integrating openCV in my project.
When i integrate in my sample application it works fine(In Targets Here i placed the compile source code as in "Objective c++")

But when i integrate the same application in to my "Main application"(In Targets Here i placed the compile source code as in "According to file type") it says error as "Lexical or preprocessor issue map file not found"

If i put the target settings in "Objective c++" then it raises an error in `ASIAuthenticationDialog.m`

I followed some answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574015/xcode-include-map-in-ml-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory).

This answer worked for me in my sample app(here i did not have any parsing i placed the compile source code as 'objective c++') But in my Main Application where i do parsing it raises error(i placed the compile source code as 'According to file type')

Please Guide me.

Comment: What is the extension of your file?

Comment: .mm where i used openCV that file only,   remaining files are .m

Comment: that's correct, it should work. What's the case if you try compiling it without Xcode?

Comment: maybe it's just a crazy setting in Xcode. What happens if you try to compile it without Xcode, only using clang/gcc from the command line?

Comment: same error i am geting @H2CO3

Comment: then you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: If it is syntax error it has to say error in that line  but i am getting error as "file not found".. How will we find where an error is?  @H2CO3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18329/discussion-between-h2co3-and-babul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at XCode's Log navigator : each build produce a log you can navigate into (showing only errors/warning), try and find exactly **WHICH** source file your compiler was trying to compile. (and also at which step it occurs : precompiled header / compiling / linking ?)

As you seem already aware, the problem might not be from OpenCV, but from your classes that depend on it - when the pre-compiler tries to solve **import** statements - I although thought that renaming your 'm' files in 'mm' solved this problem...

But if some library you're using need plain C (ASIAuthenticationDialog.m) - I guess that's the problem you're facing could rephrased : *'How do i mix C and C++ sources ?'*
Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work?lq=1) might help

Good luck !