# objective-c wrapper for namespaced c++ library (gloox)

Tags: c++, objective-c, namespaces, wrapper

Im trying to wrap the gloox library in objective-c. I have read this article [Making a Objective-C Wrapper for a C++ Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204239/making-a-objective-c-wrapper-for-a-c-library) and it is fairly straight forward however it does not cover classes that are inside a namespace. Any thoughts on how to use the technique in the article above only with a namespace?
Thanks for the help!

[edit]
Think I figured it out
add

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace gloox {
class Client;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the obvious should work when compiled as objective C++:

```
#if defined __cplusplus
namespace Foo { class MyCPPClass; }   // forward class declaration
#else
/*not sure here*/ /*namespace Foo { typedef struct MyCPPClass MyCPPClass;  }*/ // forward struct declaration
#endif

@interface MyOCClass : NSObject
{
@private
    Foo::MyCPPClass* cppObject;
} 

// methods and properties

@end
```

The Qt project has a lot of [examples](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/kernel/qapplication_mac.mm) for mixing C++ and Objective-C.

Comment: There is also another method I found where you wrap the instance declaration in #ifdef as well.